# jQuery / iScroll - Scrolling panel with clickable images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scrolling panel (using [iScroll4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) & jQuery) to navigate a horizontal list of thumbnails, like below.

[image]

Using my mouse, I can grab and slide this panel nicely, works a treat. The problem is, I have now added a click event to each image in the list, so when the user grabs and slides, it clicks on an image, causing the event to fire. This is annoying as the user didn't want to select that image, they just wanted to look further.

How can I make this so if they definitely click on the image, without a left or right movement, it selects the image, but if the scroller moves then it doesn't?

An example of what I am saying can be found on the Fotorama slider plugin [here](http://fotoramajs.com/). If you try sliding the thumbnails across and then try clicking on a thumbnail, you will see what I mean.

Any help or suggestions would marvelous.

**UPDATE**

I have found that there is an onScrollMove and onScrollEnd callbacks in the iScroll4 docs. Maybe: `onScrollEnd: function() { $(".uploaded_images").unbind("click"); }`

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

For now, I have got around this by making the images double-clickable, instead of single, but I would still like to know how it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

The Fotorama plugin is probably using a mousedown event in javascript for the dragging and if it were to slide then it disables the clicking of the thumbnail. You fix would be to simply add at the bottom more room (Padding if you will) so that the user may drag across that. Or use the Fotorama plugin. or just make it so that the user may scroll with the scrollbar and scroll wheel.
I will look into the iscroll plugin to see if i can do the mousedown event